# Index fragmentation while continuously processing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, fragmentation

SQL Server 2005

I need to be able to continuously process about 350M records in a 900M record table. The query I'm using to select the records to process becomes badly fragmented as I process and I have a need to stop the processing to rebuild the index. Pseudo data model & query ...

```
/**************************************/
CREATE TABLE [Table] 
(
    [PrimaryKeyId] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [ForeignKeyId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    /* more columns ... */
    [DataType] [CHAR](1) NOT NULL,
    [DataStatus] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [ProcessDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [ProcessThreadId] VARCHAR (100) NULL
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Idx] ON [Table] 
(
    [DataType],
    [DataStatus],
    [ProcessDate],
    [ProcessThreadId]
);
/**************************************/

/**************************************/
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) [PrimaryKeyId], [ProcessThreadId]
    FROM [Table] WITH ( ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST )
    WHERE [DataType] = 'X'
    AND [DataStatus] IS NULL
    AND [ProcessDate] < DATEADD(m, -2, GETDATE()) -- older than 2 months
    AND [ProcessThreadId] IS NULL
)
UPDATE cte
SET [ProcessThreadId] = @ProcessThreadId;

SELECT * FROM [Table] WITH ( NOLOCK )
WHERE [ProcessThreadId] = @ProcessThreadId;
/**************************************/
```

Data content...
While the column [DataType] is typed as a CHAR(1), about 35% of all the records equal 'X' with the remainder equaling 'A'.
Of only the records where [DataType] equals 'X', about 10% will have a NOT NULL [DataStatus] value.

The [ProcessDate] and [ProcessThreadId] columns will be updated for every record processed.
The [DataType] column is updated ('X' is changed to 'A') about 10% of the time.
The [DataStatus] column is updated less than 1% of the time.

For now my solution is to select the primary key of all the records to process into a separate processing table. I delete the keys as I process them so that as the index fragments I'm dealing with less records.

However, this doesn't fit the workflow I want to have so that these data are processed continuously, without manual intervention and significant downtime. I do anticipate downtime on a quarterly basis for housekeeping chores. But now, without the separate processing table, I can not get through processing even half of the data set without the fragmentation becoming so bad as to necessitate stopping and rebuilding the index.

Any recommendations for indexing or a different data model? Is there a pattern I need to research?
I have full control of the data model and the process software so nothing is off the table.

Comment: One thought too: your index appears to be wrong order: it should be most selective to least selective. So ProcessThreadId, ProcessDate, DataStatus, DataType perhaps?

Comment: We've advertised it in our chat. Very good question. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap

Comment: I updated the query to be a more accurate representation of the selection. I multiple concurrent threads running this. I've noted the selective order recommendation. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisGallucci Come to chat if you can...

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is you're using a table as a queue. Your update is the dequeue method. But the clustered index on the table is a poor choice for a queue. [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) actually impose quite stringent requirements on the table design. Your clustered index **must** be the dequeue order, in this case likely `([DataType], [DataStatus], [ProcessDate])`. You can implement the primary key as a *nonclustered* constraint. Drop the non-clustered index `Idx`, as the clustered key takes its role.

Another important piece of the puzzle is to keep the row size constant during processing. You have declared the `ProcessThreadId` as a `VARCHAR(100)` which implies the row grows and shrinks as is being 'processed' because the field value changes from NULL to non-null. This grow-and-shrink pattern on the row causes page splits and fragmentation. I can't possibly imagine a thread ID that is 'VARCHAR(100)'. Use a fixed length type, perhaps an `INT`.

As a side note, you do not need to dequeue in two steps (UPDATE followed by SELECT). You can use OUTPUT clause, as explained in the article linked above:

```
/**************************************/
CREATE TABLE [Table] 
(
    [PrimaryKeyId] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    [ForeignKeyId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    /* more columns ... */
    [DataType] [CHAR](1) NOT NULL,
    [DataStatus] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [ProcessDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [ProcessThreadId] INT NULL
);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [Cdx] ON [Table] 
(
    [DataType],
    [DataStatus],
    [ProcessDate]
);
/**************************************/

declare @BatchSize int, @ProcessThreadId int;

/**************************************/
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) [PrimaryKeyId], [ProcessThreadId] , ... more columns 
    FROM [Table] WITH ( ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST )
    WHERE [DataType] = 'X'
    AND [DataStatus] IS NULL
    AND [ProcessDate] < DATEADD(m, -2, GETDATE()) -- older than 2 months
    AND [ProcessThreadId] IS NULL
)
UPDATE cte
SET [ProcessThreadId] = @ProcessThreadId
OUTPUT DELETED.[PrimaryKeyId] , ... more columns ;
/**************************************/
```

In addition I would consider moving successfully processed items into a different, archive, table. You want your queue tables to hover near zero size, you do no want them to grow as they retain 'history' from unneeded old entries. You may also consider partitioning by `[ProcessDate]` as an alternative (ie. one current active partition that acts as the queue and stores entries with NULL ProcessDate, and another partition for everything non-null. Or multiple partitions for non-null if you want to implement efficient deletes (switch out) for data that has passed the mandated retention period. If things get hot you can partition in addition by `[DataType]` if it has enough selectivity, but that design would be really complicated as it requires partitioning by persisted computed column (a composite column that glues together [DataType] and [ProcessingDate]).

Answer (score 3):

**I would start by moving the `ProcessDate` and `Processthreadid` fields to another table.**

Right now, every row you select from this pretty wide index needs to also get updated.

If you move those two fields to another table, your update volume on the main table is cut 90%, which should take care of most of the fragmentation.

You will still have fragmentation in the NEW table, but it'll be easier to manage on a narrower table with a lot less data.

Comment: This and physically splitting the data based on [DataType] should get me where I need to be. I'm currently in the design (re-design actually) phase of this so it'll be some time before I get a chance to test drive this change.